# Simple join returns too many features in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I have to filter a Featurecollection with a certain threshold. This threshold is defined in a different Featurecollection. I want to use a simple join to filter the collection. However, if I do it it returns more then I expect. What am I doing wrong?

```
var threshold5 = threshold4.filter(ee.Filter.lessThanOrEquals('x',0.7))
print('threshold5:',threshold5)

// next a function is needed to sum and find the minimum. The minimum is saved, toghether with the bandname
var unweighted = function(img){
  var uni = img.reduceRegions({
    reducer: ee.Reducer.sum().unweighted(),
    collection: grid,
    scale:500}).map(function(feat){
      var id = ee.String(feat.get('system:index')).cat('-').cat(ee.String(img.get('system:index')));
      var date = ee.String(img.get('system:index'));
      var bandNames = img.bandNames().map(function(name){return ee.Number.parse(name)});
      var values = ee.Feature(feat).toDictionary(img.bandNames()).values();
      var array = ee.Array.cat([values, bandNames], 1);
      var min = array.reduce(ee.Reducer.min(2), [0], 1);
      var key = ee.String(min.get([0,1]).toInt());
      var value = min.get([0,0]);
      return ee.Feature(feat.setMulti(ee.Dictionary.fromLists(['Minimum', 'value', 'id'], [key, value, id])));
    });
    return uni; 
};

var C = B.map(unweighted).flatten();
var joinfilter = ee.Filter.stringContains({leftField:'id',rightField:'id'})
var join = ee.Join.simple().apply({
  primary:C,
  secondary:threshold5,
  condition: joinfilter
});
print(join)
```

[link to full code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/887ccac8b99a6206f7053f0f0fa975fb)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that your `joinfilter` isn't what you expect.

Try replacing:

```
var joinfilter = ee.Filter.stringContains({leftField:'id',rightField:'id'})
```

With:

```
var joinfilter = ee.Filter.equals({leftField:'id',rightField:'id'});
```